# How do I make a button cycle throught outputs and toggle lamps?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

I want a system where if a button is pressed, it produces an output of 1. Press it again, and go up to 2. If it is below 5, I will measure it and light up a lamp that has a sign on it that says "a". Above 5 it will change from the "a" lamp and turn on a lamp that has a sign labelling it "b". How can I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by “an output of 1.” Do you mean power levels, or something else?

Comment: Yes, power levels

Comment: Do you want this to be resettable (set it back to zero again)?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, make lecterns each with 15 pages, and turned to 1,2,3, and so on. If you want a zero, just make a block as a placeholder. Then, use these lecterns in a block chain to where it basically circles after 15 presses. Then, hook up a comparator to the output you want, and when you press the button, presto! the pistons making the circle move will push the blocks one after another to make the next lectern move in front of the comparator and the signal will be outputted. I hope this helps, if it doesn't tell me and I will soon make a picture to display. Happy 'Crafting!